# Attach preventdefault to a .submit that calls a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(function() {
    $('#login').submit(function(e){
        login();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}); 

function login() {
    $('#btnLogin').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $("#btnLogin").css('background', 'url(/imgs/submit.gif) 50% -3px');
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $("#btnLogin").css('color', 'transparent');     
    $.post(url, data).done(function(data) {
        $('#btnLogin').removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#btnLogin").css('color', '#ffffff');
        $("#btnLogin").css('background', '#4ea885');
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if(data === false) {
            $(".cover").append('<div class="alert alert-warning">We\'re sorry, that password does not match the username or email address provided.</div>');
        } else if (data == true) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
```

}

I tried various way, I want to attach #login to the function login and prevent from being submitted

Comment: What you have is correct, but if your `login()` function is throwing an error, the `e.preventDefault()` won't be reached. So check your console for errors.

Comment: ...my money's on `data` not being valid JSON.

Comment: ...but change `login()` to `login.call(this)` so that the value of `this` in `login` will be set to the `#login` element.

Comment: Can you check my answer and see if that's the case

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#login').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        login();

    });
});
```

Comment: That gives me a syntax error, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: check it once again dear!!

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have specified in your question is almost correct. The problem is with the $(this) part in your login() function. $(this) doesn't have scope to access your form attributes. If my guess is right $(this).attr('action') will be returning 'undefined', which is causing your post request to fail, in turn your e.preventDefault doesn't even execute. So your form is just getting posted. Can you check your console and let us know if you are getting any errors there.

Replace

```
var url = $(this).attr('action');
var data = $(this).serialize();
```

with

```
var url = $('#login').attr('action');
var data = $('#login').serialize();
```

If this is not the problem please comment, I will check it once again.